# DNS-SD on client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, dns-sd

Is it possible to discover services using DNS-SD on **client** side using some JS library (so to discover services on client's local network)? I found a lot of libraries on npmjs.com, but they all work on Node.js, not on client-side JS.

Comment: [Not any longer](https://www.w3.org/TR/discovery-api/), no.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [sample app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mdns-browser/kipighjpklofchgbdgclfaoccdlghidp) in the Chrome Web Store.

mDNS browser
This is a non-trivial sample which uses the UDP multicast support in Chrome Packaged Apps to browse mDNS servers. mDNS protocol is usually used for home appliance devices, like the Apple's Bonjour. Read more about the mDNS protocol at this Wikipedia's article

See the source code at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/mdns-browser

Answer (score 1):

DNS is (historically) a UDP-based protocol. Browsers traditionally sandbox the networking capabilities and allow to send only HTTP or HTTPS (i.e. TCP) requests from JavaScript code. So, the short answer is **No**.

However, if you truly need this feature, you could look into the [DNS-over-HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS) technology which got some traction recently. Alternatively, you can try searching for ways of sending UDP packets from the browser. I don't have much knowledge in that domain but WebAssembly or WebRTC potentially may have something implemented already.

Comment: I doubt that DoH works from the browser - the DNS resolver would need to support CORS, and I cannot imagine how it would be used for local service discovery.